# How can I make an input allowing only certain Names?

Tags: vue.js, file, validation, upload

Hello guys I have the following code input :

```
 <v-file-input
      class="mx-6"
      show-size
      accept=".xlsx"
      label="File input"
      @change="selectFile"
    ></v-file-input>
```

How can I make it accept only specific names.xlsx? Like it will accept xlsx files containing specific words in It.

```
Example:
name-george.xlsx true
name-anna.xlsx false
george-surname.xlsx true
```

I want It to contain george word inside the xlsx File Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a validation rule. Here is an example to get you started

https://codepen.io/radvic/pen/XWYxKpQ

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    rules: [
      v => {
        for(index in v){
          const fileName = v[index].name;
           if(fileName.match(/george(.*)\.xlsx/g) === null){   
             return 'The file name "'+fileName+'" is wrong';
           }
        }
        return true;          
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input multiple :rules="rules" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"></v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: At your run Code snippet is running good and that what I want but when I put it to my code it says index is not defined

Comment: literally i tried everything didnt work. Is there a problem because im working on Vue2?

Comment: my solution is with vue 2, you might have copied something wrong